# Interpretation of MLR model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

[image]I've done a MLR model to determine and analyze what factors affect life expectancy. This is my data^. For the variable estimates, could you help me answer: Significance (one-sided alternatives), Sign (are there any signs as to be expected?), and Magnitude?
In addition, I was wondering how you can see which variable is the most effective in increasing LE and which variable is having the best (in terms of the R2-value) predictive power for LE?

Thank you in advance!